# Fetch max value of a column from a table joined with many table

Tags: sql, oracle, max

I want to fetch max value of seq for each id

with a sample query :

```
SELECT a.id, a.seq, ... FROM TableA a, TableB b, ...
WHERE a.id = b.id, ...
```

`id` and `seq` is primary key. 
TableB will be joined with other table by TableB's foreign key. 
Without using group by because I will join several tables with many extracted columns and a lot of where_clause, thus I will need to write a lot of group by columns.

In other words, I want to select only row with `max(seq)` for each unique `id`.

Please make the scenario works with theoritically infinite columns, tables, and where_clause. Preferable in Oracle database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to use `OVER()` and `PARTITION BY` appropriately:

```
SELECT a.id,
    MAX(seq) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id)
FROM TableA a, TableB b 
WHERE a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Ideally, you would use an explicit join between your two tables:

```
SELECT a.id,
    MAX(seq) OVER (PARTITION BY a.id)
FROM TableA a
    INNER JOIN TableB b on a.id = b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` for this:

```
SELECT id, seq 
FROM (
SELECT a.id, a.seq, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY seq DESC) AS rn
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.id) AS t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

If, in case of ties, you want to return *all* records having the maximum `seq` value, then use `RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.